# string handling in Ruby on Rails bring difficulties

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid, cancan

I am using Cancan
In my user model there is

```
ROLES = %w[admin user ram]
```

I want to bring the value from my own module .

```
 all= Role.all
 @all.each do |all|
 all.name
 end
```

Here i can carry all value that are in database from roll model.
and i want to keep it inside %w[]
like  `

```
ROLES = %w[ all= Role.all
     @all.each do |all|
     all.name
     end]
```

But I don know the format.

Comment: use roles instead of ROLES as it is not a constant

Answer (score 2):

Try `pluck`:

```
ROLES = Role.pluck(:name)
```

More info on APIdock: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck

Comment: undefined method `pluck' for Role:Class

Comment: Which version of ActiveRecord are you using?

Comment: (cont.) Pluck is only available in Rails 3.2+

Answer (score 0):

%w[] is just a fancy way to create an array.
If you want this should work the same way.

```
ROLES = @all.collect! {|item| item.name }
```

Comment: 1.9.3p194 :001 > %w[admin user ram]
 => ["admin", "user", "ram"]  I know it give such result. I want to bring my users in this format.